# Android Studio findViewById throwing error when finding EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, findviewbyid

I'm very new to Android Development and am just learning some very basic stuff. In my MainActivity.java file I'm trying to use the EditText that I have created in the XML file. In the XML file, I have set an ID by stating:

```
android:id=@+id/ageRecieved
```

When I go to the java file and type:

```
EditText ageInput = findViewById(R.id.ageRecieved);
```

it then has a pop up message that says "Incompatible Types. Required: android.widget.EditText   Found: android.view.View

Very confused why it's doing this. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: `findViewById(...)` returns a `View`, so a cast is necessary to `EditText`, which is a subclass of `TextView`, which a subclass of `View`.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
EditText ageInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ageRecieved);
```

you need to cast your view.

Answer (score 0):

The method `findViewById(int id)`, as the name said, finds (and return) a View with a given id. So it returns a View object,and it's up to programmer to cast the View to a more specialized object: in your case, you should downcast  it to an EditTextView,otherwise the jvm throws an error,because you can't assign a View object to an EditTextView reference.
 hope this was useful,bye!

Answer (score 0):

findViewById return a View object, when you want to work with EditText, TextView or other child of View object you must cast it.

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ageRecieved);
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ageRecieved);
```